# Ionic - OCR : ReferenceError TesseractPlugin is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ocr

I try to develop an ionic app and I would like add an optical character recognition (OCR).

I have install the cordova camera plugin and I would like use this github project (tesseract): https://github.com/gustavomazzoni/cordova-plugin-tesseract

But, when I use this function, I have the following error into my javascript console :

> ionic.bundle.js:26799 ReferenceError: TesseractPlugin is not defined

The following command display : `cordova plugin list` :

> cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1 "Camera"
>
> cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
>
> cordova-plugin-tesseract 0.0.1 "Tesseract Plugin"
>
> phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 6.0.5 "BarcodeScanner"

Here is my controller code :

```js
'Use Strict';

angular.module('App')

    .controller('CameraOCRController', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {


        TesseractPlugin.loadLanguage(language, function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function(reason) {
            deferred.reject('Error on loading OCR file for your language. ' + reason);
        });

        $scope.takePhoto = function () {
            var options = {
                quality: 75,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 300,
                targetHeight: 300,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };
            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

                TesseractPlugin.recognizeText(imageData, language, function(recognizedText) {
                    $scope.text = recognizedText;
                }, function(reason) {
                    alert('Error on recognizing text from image. ' + reason);
                });

            }, function (err) {
                alert("An error occured. Show a message to the user"+err);
            });
        };

    });
```

I don't see my error.

Comment: Did you fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you wait for `deviceready` to fire before referencing the plugin?